# how to debug react router not loading component on url change

Tags: reactjs

I'm using react-router-dom version 4.3.1
Upon clicking the link, the URL changes but React Component is not rendered (in fact the debugger does not stop at any point in my code).
I have already tried using `withComponent` and `exact` keywords, but that doesn't work as well. It is mentioned in the following two solutions:
[React router changes url but not view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43351752/react-router-changes-url-but-not-view) and
[react route using browserhistory changes url but nothing happens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44328600/react-route-using-browserhistory-changes-url-but-nothing-happens)
The only time it works is when the page is refreshed using the refresh button.
I'm loading the router in the `root` element in `index.js`:

`ReactDOM.render(<AppRouter />, document.getElementById("root"));`

AppRouter has this code:

```
export const AppRouter = () => {
    return (
        <>
        <HashRouter>
        <div>
        <Switch>
        <Route path="/page1" component={Page1} />
        <Route path="/page1" component={withRouter(Page2)} /> //still doesn't work
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
        </Switch>
        </div>
        </HashRouter>
        </>
        )}
```

Then in my page I have:

```
<Router>
        <div>
        <Link to={'/page1'}>Page 1</Link>
        <Link to={'/page2'}>Page 2</Link>
        </div>
</Router>
```

What's interesting is that it was working but after I shuffled around load order of my components, it stopped working. How can I debug this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesting a router in a router can cause this kind of problem. Upon clicking on the `<Link>`
you update the history stack in the top `<Router>` element and not on the `<HashRouter>`
. I think if you delete the inner `<Router>` every thing should start working.

```
export const AppRouter = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <HashRouter>
        <div>
          <Link to={"/page1"}>Page 1</Link>
          <Link to={"/page2"}>Page 2</Link>
        </div>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route path="/page1" component={Page1} />
            <Route path="/page1" component={withRouter(Page2)} /> //still
            doesn't work
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </HashRouter>
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Also I followed this: https://flaviocopes.com/react-router/ apparently you cannot have a `Link` outside of a `Router`, `React` throws an error.

Comment: Exactly, is you link elements are inside page1 or page2 ? I will update my post with a working exemple.

Comment: Thanks for posting code David. I want to have `Link` and `Route` in different files like you can see here: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-johnson-9h7p4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark In this case I'm getting this error: `Invariant failed: You should not use <Switch> outside a <Router>
`

Comment: I fixed your sandbox, they were alot of mistakes presents. https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-water-jibnk?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark

Comment: This is how the architecture should be. You can message me if you have more questions on the structure.

Comment: Btw <Switch> is like a switch case, the first matching path is the one that will be rendering so you should place "/" at the end.

Comment: Thanks David. I don't see the updates on codesandbox.io link though. Maybe you have to click on 'share' and get a new link for changes to show?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-water-jibnk-updated-t3iwk
is this one working ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205712/discussion-between-codebee-and-david-desjardins).

Answer (score 0):

The `<Router>` on your Page component is not necessary, as you are defining a `<Router>` within another one. Besides, you might have a typo:

```
        <Route path="/page1" component={Page1} />
        <Route path="/page1" component={withRouter(Page2)} /> //still doesn't work
        <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
```

Second line should have `path='/page2'`, as you render `Page2` on the `component` prop.